# Braces After Initialization Lists

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization-list

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(double InitValue): StoredDouble(InitValue)
    {
    }

    double StoredDouble;
}
```

Is there a syntax that will allow me to skip out on the curly braces after the initialization list?  I know it's a minor thing, but I'd like to be as concise as possible in my code.

Comment: For conciseness, you could put the curly braces on the same line as the initialization list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `Foo( double InitValue )` is actually a method and all methods must have opening and closing braces.

Answer (score 5):

No.

*[[Excess padding to make my answer 30 characters long]]*